# Migrate ASP from root to subdirectory

Tags: asp.net, subdirectory

I'm in the process of converting an existing ASP website into PHP while retaining the ASP website as an older version.  Since I'm not an ASP developer, I thought it would be simple as moving the contents of the root directory into its own directory that I've labeled as v1.0 so that the ASP version can be viewed by going to www.mysite.com/v1.0 while the new PHP version (v2.0) can be viewed by going to www.mysite.com

Herein lies the problem.  Doing this causes flags all kinds of errors (all related to "Server Error in '/' Application. Runtime errors").  The best I can figure out is that the web.config file needs to be tweaked in the v2.0 directory.  Can any of you ASP experts recommend a simple solution to make this happen?  I would like to have an empty root directory if possible since the new v2.0 version will be in all PHP and want to "self contain" the ASP version within the v1.0 directory as much as possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Classic ASP pages use Server Side Includes, if the site is using a SSI such as:
`<!-- #include virtual = "include-file.inc" -->`
, then you will need to change all of these to be
`<!-- #include virtual = "v1.0/include-file.inc" -->`.

I assume that you are using IIS 7 or IIS 7.5, since you are not seeing the actual error, you will need to modify your web.config file.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" />
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Reference:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/564/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default/

**Update**
Since it now sounds like you are using ASP.NET, you would need to change your web.config as below to see the full error:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I checked the .aspx files and there are no include statements.  When I move all the contents of the root directory over to v1.0, this is the first error I encounter when attempting to go to www.mysite.com/v1.0/default.aspx:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: Additonal Note: I did incorporate your changes to the web.config file and it still produced the same error message mentioned above.

Comment: That was more for Classic ASP for ASP.NET you would need to change the customErrors element, updated answer.

Comment: OK did that, and now the next error message says: Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.  The error in the web.config file is at "<trust level="Full"/>"

Comment: Try removing the <trust level="Full"/> from your web.config, just comment it out.

Comment: Well, yes, I commented the trust level from web.config and it continued to give errors with the same parser error message as noted above with another line in the web.config file that it couldn't interpret so I kept commenting out all the lines that it couldn't interpret until the 5th or 6th line and stopped there as it wasn't making any sense to keep commenting out lines....

Comment: Without seeing the actual errors it is going to be hard to track down, you may want to try making v1.0 its own application in IIS.

Comment: OK - that solved it.  A bit of learning on my part - I created v1.0 as its own application in IIS and it now works!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of wrangling, finally figured out that I needed to set up v1.0 as its own application under the IIS control panel.  Once that was done, then all the contents of the root directory could be moved over to the v1.0 sub-directory and viewed via www.mysite.com/v1.0 -- thanks to [Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/805431/sean)! for his help!